# Laptop low cpu clock speed / multiplier

Tags: cpu, speed, clock, multiplier

Couple of days ago i have noticed drops in the performance of my laptop. I couldnt stream  a movie or surf web on more than one web pages without lag even though i have 8gb ram and ssd installed on my laptop. Today i had a chance to review the issue. I have checked all lately installed programs and updates. Only thing that stand out was external graphic driver update on the day problem started. I tried rolling back that update and when it didn't work disabling the external graphic driver. That didn't help neither. I have also updated all drivers including bios and checked bios settings. Only thing wrong with the pc was that cpu speed stuck at 498 mhz and clock speed at 5x. (Checked with cpu-z and prime95 torture set no changes). I was able to resolve the issue by using throttlestop application and disabling bd prochot.  I know this is not a permanent a solution. Any ideas regarding this issue?

Thanks

Lenovo Yoga 500 - 14IBD 
CPU: I5-5200U
Win 10 - 64 bit
8gb ram  and 128 gb ssd installed over standart hardware.

Comment: You haven't mentioned any temperatures... Is your laptop getting uncomfortably hot to the touch? If so, this could be a sign of severe thermal throttling.

Comment: I have been using the laptop without BD_PROCHOT for a week now. Temperature is between 40-50 in normal workload and 60-70 max. I don't remember laptop getting hotter than usual.